# 4 pin switch circuit causes Arduino to reboot when pressed

Tags: arduino, switches, breadboard

I'm trying to copy an example that shows hooking up 4 pin switches to the Arduino (http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/207/Lab3/).

The problem is when the button is pressed the Arduino reboots. I have no idea why and I don't want to damage anything so I thought I'd ask here.

Here's a diagram of the circuit:

[image]

And here's mine:. I have it going to pin 2 (0 indexed pins).

[image]

Is there anything wrong with my circuit?

Comment: Because when you press your button, with the way you've wired it, you short out your power supply.

Comment: I can see you put resistor wrong way. Use separate line. Attach + to rail 8 and resistor 8-7 then button on 7 rail. now you are making short circuit. Look at your resistor in drawing and in photo.

Comment: @Martynas like so? http://imgur.com/a/iZIux ...why can't the resistor go on rail 6 and do away with need for a small jumper?

Comment: Yes like this, but you can get rid of that jumper :D pit resistor to rail 6, i didnt paid much attention to rail numbers :))

Comment: If you put as answer I will accept. I see what I done now, I put the + on the same rail as the resistor which I assume was pushing 5v into the pin.

Comment: May I ask why the downvotes for future reference?

Comment: It might be because even though you had a diagram you didn't install it the way it said and that's why your circuit doesn't work. But I can understand how you made that mistake. For reference, [here is what the internal connections of the breadboard looks like](http://anceop.com/images/misc/tp4/tp4-2-breadboard.png).

Comment: Ok noted. I'm new to electronics and circuits and just getting the hang of things. I did try to solve the problem before asking the question but I didn't want to risk trying anything else incase I messed up the Arduino. All is good. I now have MIDI output working too :) Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration in the first diagram consists of a pull-up resistor connected to a switch which is tied to ground. The idea is when the switch is not pressed it sends a LOW signal to Pin 2. When it is pressed, a HIGH signal is passed to the pin. The purpose of the pullup is to eliminate any "in-between" signals and send either a LOW or HIGH at all times. The resistor is for current limiting - you don't want your 5V passing current through the switch into the pin.

In your photo you've placed both your resistor leads in the same breadboard conductor track, essentially attaching a short circuit in parallel with your resistor. This allows current to flow through the pin which shorts out your power supply and the Arduino reboots to protect itself.

To correct this you should follow the first diagram and exactly place the resistor so that its contacts land in different conductor tracks, [see this diagram for what the internal connections of a breadboard look like.](http://anceop.com/images/misc/tp4/tp4-2-breadboard.png)